# Navigating to another Fragment stack in multi back stacks app with the new Navigation Component library

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I'm using new Navigation Component library (version 2.4.0-alpha01), which introduced support for multiple back stacks.

**My question is: how can I navigate programatically to any destination in any Fragment back stack?**

Taking for example Google's [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) project, I would want to navigate from Title fragment to UserProfile fragment, which belong to separate menu items in the bottom navigation bar.

Creating XML action and calling `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_title_to_leaderboard)` in the Title fragment results in following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample:id/leaderboard referenced from action com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample:id/action_title_to_leaderboard cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample:id/titleScreen) label=Home class=com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.homescreen.Title
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1190)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1128)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1110)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1093)
    at com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.homescreen.Title$onCreateView$1.onClick(Title.kt:38)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Is it supported by navigation 2.4.0-alpha01 release?

Comment: It says destination not found. You've to create destinations from one fragment to other in the nav_graph.xml first. Even the example you've shared has them for every fragment.

Comment: Linked example shows only how to navigate between destinations in the same nested graph. Each nested graph has its own backstack, so I think it's more tricky problem, but I surely may be wrong.